# C# .How to make sure, that the end result of ordering a list of objects by a string property is the same on every computer

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of complex objects, and I want to sort that list by a string property. Now the problem is that the string contains Lithuanian letters (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithuanian_orthography), and the end result of List.OrderBy() looks differently on my friends computer than on mines. Is there a way to ensure, that the list will be ordered the same way on every computer ?

I tried adding

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("lt-LT");
var testModel = model.products.OrderBy(x => x.title, StringComparer.CurrentCulture).ToList();
```

but it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `StringComparer.CurrentCulture`.
This may be different on your friend's systems.

Specify a Culture for the the `OrderBy()` method explixitly (recommended). You could also use `InvariantCulture` although this might not be the best choice for texts that are presented in the UI.

Also, consider using an overload of the OrderBy() method that takes the [StringComparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum, which allows for more control how the comparison should be handled.

The MSDN has an excellent article here: [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: They are setting the culture on the current thread ahead of time.  Could there still be a difference after it?

Comment: @Khan: That is what the method overload is for : It overrides both the system settings and whatever else the current thread may be - but only for that single OrderBy() call.

Comment: Microsoft changed the [behavior for threads and its added culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#culture-and-threads). [And culture dependent order can changed over time  with new .NET versions - even in InvariantCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus)! Therefore use best `StringComparision.Ordinal` (this leads to always identical sort order, no matter of .NET or OS changes) for e. g. persiting data. IMHO only use culture dependency for UI output.

Answer (score 4):

Try specifying the culture explicitly rather than relying on the current thread culture:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("lt-LT");
var testModel = model.products.OrderBy(x => x.title,
                                       StringComparer.Create(culture, false));
```

There *might* also be differences based on the settings of the machine and/or differences in .NET version (I'm not an expert on Lithuanian culture settings so I can't say for sure).